# Is "Fellow" informal? If yes, what's a formal equivalent?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms, formality

In [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Avoid-Colloquial-%28Informal%29-Writing) article I read that:

> Fellow – Avoid using "fellow" when you mean "a person." Calling someone a fellow is more formal than calling him or her a dude, but "fellow" is still a colloquialism.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42315/what-can-i-call-other-students-if-i-am-also-a-student) ensures that "fellow student" is correct, but I need to know whether it is formal usage or not.

I am writing a formal application and want to refer to a fellow university student.

Should I use "fellow student" or do I have a better choice?

Comment: "Fellow student" is just fine. "A fellow I know" is not. "Come hither, fellow" is rude, but chances are nobody will know.

Comment: The article is talking about the noun. You are asking about the adjective. It expressly says to avoid *fellow* when you mean "a person". You do not mean "a person". You mean "of the same group".

Comment: The ["Fellows of the {various} Royal Societies"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fellow+of+the+royal+society%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) probably wouldn't consider that to be an "informal" designation.

Comment: Thank you @StoneyB and @RegDwighт♦ 
You fully covered me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per ODO, only one of the definitions of [fellow](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fellow) is considered informal:

> (**informal**) a man or boy:
>
> *he was an extremely obliging **fellow***

Other uses are fine:

> *he was learning with a rapidity unique among his **fellows***
>
> *a **fellow** of the Geological Society*
>
> *they urged the troops not to fire on their **fellow** citizens*