# Is there a noun in English denoting the relation of attending the same school/class?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

Is there a noun in English denoting the relation of attending the same school/class? In other words:

Being friends → *friendship*

Being neighbours → *geographical contiguity*

Attending the same school → *School fellowship*?

Attending the same class → *Class fellowship*?

Comment: You can be schoolmates or classmates with someone. A fellow can be an entirely different beast when you talk about some schools.

Comment: Maybe you could live with *class companionship*?

Comment: Some decent answers here.. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42315/what-can-i-call-other-students-if-i-am-also-a-student

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen: None of those answer this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right but the discussion is similar and further evolved albeit not exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Future Alumni - but not a single word, unfortunately. [disambiguation here](http://www1.uwindsor.ca/alumni/alumnus-alumnae-alumni) If you say both words together really fast and it catches on in popularity maybe 50 years from now it will evolve into one word and considered official by some English dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

## *Classmate*

It may seem simple, but I like this option because it can be used both in the context of the same class as well as attending the same school.

Comment: I like classmate but it is on the same level as "friend". I'm looking for a noun on the same level as "friendship". So: is there a noun (1 word) denoting the relation of "being classmate"?

Comment: Does "classmateship" exist?

Comment: We don't have a word for the classmate relationship - at least not one that I can come up with.

Comment: So then the answer is "no", not the answer given here.

Answer (score 0):

## *Peer*

> A person who is equal to another in abilities, qualifications, age, background, and social status.

This is more general but would fit in your example.